# Writing multiple feature spec expectations from a single action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

So I'm writing my feature test and it goes something like this, note the `[[place_holder]]`

```
feature 'Accounts' do
  scenario 'creating an account' do
    # visit and fill form
    expect {
      click_button 'Create Account'
    }.to [[place_holder]]
    success_message = 'Your account has been successfully created.'
    expect(page).to have_content(success_message)
  end
end
```

Now I want to somehow place 2 expecations for this block, these expectations are

```
change(User, :count).by(1)
change(Account, :count).by(1)
```

Is there a way I could like chain these two exectations into one, yea I know I could just do a test for each in it's scenario, but that code is too WET, no need for duplications, and the feature specs are slow to begin with, no need to make my test suite slower.

Any suggestions/alternatives are appriceated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From rspec 3.1, you can use compound matcher expressions with block expectations.

```
expect {
  click_button 'Create Account'
}.to change(User, :count).by(1).and change(Account, :count).by(1)
```

http://rspec.info/blog/2014/09/rspec-3-1-has-been-released/#expectations-block-matchers-can-now-be-used-in-compound-expressions

Comment: Yea that worked, tested a failing and a passing spec and both seem to be working as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data will presumably be cleared between each test run, you could just check the absolute value, e.g.

```
expect(User.count).to eq(1)
expect(Account.count).to eq(1)
```

I think this is more readable.

Comment: I don't like depending on such conditions, if the spec is edited for any reason and the database changes to hold more than 1 user or 1 account in the same spec then the whole thing fails, and if it did pass I wouldn't know for sure if this user was created because of this form or because of some previous action in the same spec.